# XAML definition to build a TreeView with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I'm trying to build a TreeView using `MVVM` in a `WPF` App but I don't understand how to handle `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. My `TreeView` should represent a folder structure which contains folders within folders and so on.

My folder `ViewModel` is defined as follows:

```
public class TreeViewFolderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _id;
    private int _parentId;
    private string _text;
    private string _key;
    private ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel> _children;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return this._id; }
        set { Set(() => Id, ref this._id, value); }
    }

    public int ParentId
    {
        get { return this._parentId; }
        set { Set(() => ParentId, ref this._parentId, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return this._text; }
        set { Set(() => Text, ref this._text, value); }
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get { return this._key; }
        set { Set(() => Key, ref this._key, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return this._children ?? (this._children = 
              new ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel>()); }
        set { Set(() => Children, ref this._children, value); }
    }
}
```

My model has the same structure as my `ViewModel` so the final `ViewModel` is a list of folders that contain child folders and so forth. I'm using recursion to load all these folders and that part is working fine.

Where I'm stuck is on how to define and load this ViewModel into the actual TreeView.

I've read [Hierarchical DataBinding in TreeView using MVVM pattern](https://wpftution.blogspot.ie/2012/06/hierarchical-databinding-in-treeview.html) and while I more or less understand what's going on, but each of the levels of the `TreeView` represent a different object type while my `TreeView` has only one object type and I'm confused as to how I'm suppose to define this.

The Root `ViewModel` property in my MainWindowViewModel is of type `TreeViewFolderViewModel` which means I have a single object which represents to root of my TreeView. This object has Children of type `TreeViewFolderViewModel` which in turn have also Children of type `TreeViewFolderViewModel` and so forth

How do I defined this in `XAML`? I have the following defined:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding RootFolder}"/>
```

And I've got a `Hierarchical` template defined as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
     DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SharePointFolderTreeViewViewModel}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

But nothing is loading up.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a small sample to illustrate.

**ViewModels**

```
public class TreeViewFolderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }

    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel> children;
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return children ?? (children =
            new ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel>());
        }
        set { children = value; OnPropertyChanged("Children"); }
    }
}

public class TreeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<TreeViewFolderViewModel> items;
    public List<TreeViewFolderViewModel> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
    }

    public TreeViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<TreeViewFolderViewModel>()
        {
            new TreeViewFolderViewModel()
            {
                Id =0, Text="RootFolder", Children=new ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel>()
                {
                    new TreeViewFolderViewModel() { Id = 10, Text = "FirstFolder", Children=new ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel>() { new TreeViewFolderViewModel() { Id = 11, Text = "FirstChild" } } } ,
                    new TreeViewFolderViewModel() { Id = 20, Text = "SecondFolder", Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel>() { new TreeViewFolderViewModel() { Id = 21, Text = "SecondChild" } } } ,
                    new TreeViewFolderViewModel() { Id = 30, Text = "ThirdFolder", Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewFolderViewModel>() { new TreeViewFolderViewModel() { Id = 31, Text = "ThirdChild" } } }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TreeViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>    
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
                                  DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewFolderViewModel}">
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Id" />
                        <Binding Path="Text" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>    
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I must be missing something as it's still not working for me. My TreeView's ItemSource is definitely set correctly. I've changed my `HierarchicalDataTemplate ` to match yours (Same really). My biggest mistake was to treat the root as an node when it should really have been part of a list itself. I've modified that part and I can clearly see the final list being a list that contains the root node in its Children list property and each of these children have children of their own. The only difference is that I'm using an `ObservableCollection` instead of a list. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that I'm getting the follow error in my output window: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Children' property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=51831188)'. BindingExpression:Path=Folders.Children; DataItem='ChooseFolderDialogViewModel' (HashCode=9691954); target element is 'TreeView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable'). That's obviously why my Treeview is still empty. Will keep looking into it and update if I find something.

Comment: Ok, found my problem. I stupidly left `ItemsSource="{Binding Folders.Children}"` when it was suppose to be `ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}". Everything is loading as expected. In short, I should have added my root as a child of the folder's list. Many thanks once again!